# Passing string properly to eval() in python

Tags: python, eval

my question is in regard to eval() 'ing a string that contains trusted-user input. I am not sure how to properly package the string (first line after try:). An exception is raised on eval() in the example below. Any help would be highly appreciated. Here is an example code:

```
import ast

def do_set_operation_on_testids_file(str_filename1, str_filename2, str_set_operation):
  resulting_set = None
    with open(str_filename1) as fid1:
      with open(str_filename2) as fid2:
        list1 = fid1.readlines()
        list2 = fid2.readlines()

        try:
            str_complete_command = "set(list1)." + str_set_operation + "(set(list2))"
            resulting_set = ast.literal_eval(str_complete_command)
            for each_line in resulting_set:
                print(each_line.strip().strip('\n'))
        except:
            print('Invalid set operation provided: ' + str_set_operation)
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: What happens if you try this?

Comment: What is the value of `str_complete_command` before you try to eval it?

Comment: An exception is raised. But I am sure yet how to catch and print out the exception.

Comment: str_complete_command is:

Comment: 'set(list1).intersection(set(list2))'

Comment: Instead of `except`, use `except Exception, e` and then include `str(e)` in your print statement.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for pointing to the alternative. I am still curious as to how to properly package a string to pass to eval() as in _'set(list1).intersection(set(list2))'_

Comment: @MarkBronstein well, first, `literal_eval()` is very safe, it doesn't know what is `list1` and `list2` - you need to pass them into the string. Also, `literal_eval()` would not do the actual `intersection()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `literal_eval()` or `eval()` at all.

Use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the set operation method by string:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,2,4]
>>> list2 = [2,4,5,4]
>>> str_set_operation = "intersection"
>>> set1 = set(list1)
>>> set2 = set(list2)
>>> getattr(set1, str_set_operation)(set2)
set([2, 4])
```

Alternatively, you can pass an [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) function instead of a string with set method name. Example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> def do_set_operation_on_sets(set1, set2, f):
...     return f(set1, set2)
... 
>>> do_set_operation_on_sets(set1, set2, operator.and_)
set([2, 4])
```

where `and_` would call `set1 & set2`, which is an intersection of sets.